# Two text views with no margin(spacing)

Tags: android, layout, textview

I would like to achieve something like this:

I need that these two texviews would not have space between them. I specify no margin to them, but android already has a little bit margin by default and makes a little bit space. I would like to shrink that space :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give negative margin to view.

Answer (score 1):

1. try to set **TextView's** background `#0000`(transparent).
2. try to set **margin** `left=-5dp` or something to second **TextView**

Answer (score 1):

Set same background for both `TextView`

You can specify `Minus Margin` like `android:marginLeft=-5dp` for Right side `TextView` or `android:marginRight=-5dp` for Left side `TextView`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a second TextView inside the First one like

In XML, create a Second TextView like:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/firstTxtView"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/firstTxtView"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/firstTxtView"
```